# Is it possible to copy an array while looping through it? java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there is a way of copying an array while looping through it?

So, I want to send a copy of the current elements that were just added to the array, while the looping process is still not done, to another method in the class to process it and then return to the loop in the previous method.

I assume, if possible, it could be something like that:

```
String[] a = new String[10];

for (loop) {
  a[0] = "Hello";
  anotherMethod(Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length));
  }

 // anotherMethod(a) will get a copy of the array showing the
 // first index of a, which is `Hello`, and will do similarly
 // every time the first loop calls it.
```

Comment: Why do you think its not possible? Did you get an error when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @Henry It gave me an empty copy with no elements

Comment: `for (loop)`: I hope that is not your actual code.

Comment: @NickJ hahahaha! I hope the same

Comment: So, as already pointed out: it is possible. Another question is *why* you want to do that. It smells a bit like an inefficient algorithm (because if you do that, the loop runs in O(n²)).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Myclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] array=new String[10]; 

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){

            System.out.println("current counter is:"+i);
            array[i]="text "+String.valueOf(i);
            showStringTextConsole(Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length));
        }


    }

    static void showStringTextConsole(String[] array){

        for (String text:array){
            System.out.println(text);
        }

        System.out.println("----end of array-----");

    }

}
```

Copy it to your IDE and check.It works fine.